# Dell PowerConnect 5448 QoS policy based on TCP port specification?

Tags: switch, qos, dell-powerconnect

I am working with a set of [Dell PowerConnect 5448 switches](http://www.dell.com/us/enterprise/p/powerconnect-5448/pd) where I'm trying to prioritize traffic for specific TCP ports/services. In this case, it's a production warehouse printing environment, and I'm looking to improve port 515 and port 9100 socket performance on a congested network.

I know this switch is QoS capable, but how do I create useful maps for QoS?

Comment: What version of firmware are you running?